# "Error 1059: Circular service dependency was specified." except there isn't

Tags: windows, windows-services, dependencies

When trying to start a specific Windows service, the error message "Error 1059: Circular service dependency was specified." is shown. However, having manually checked the dependency tree, there are no circular dependencies.

How do I find out what Windows thinks is the dependency chain, given that all information in the Services snap-in shows that there is no circular dependency?

Answer (score 0):

After having the same issue I just figured this out. I had configured this server using an AzureAD account. The error when away after changing this to use the local system account.